# Updating database for specific user

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to updata my sql database for a specific name, and the following code is not working. Any ideas why?

Here is what I am doing on the button click:

```
string person = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
string memberStatus = "platinum";
string conn = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Client Set Role = @Status  WHERE Name = @name");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", memberStatus);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", person);
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

When I check the database, the Client's Role has not been updated. And when I debug, the value of person is "System.Data.DataRowView" Why is that? How can i fix it?

Comment: When I check the database, the Client's Role has not been updated.

Comment: Does `person` have the value you expect?

Comment: Sounds like you where clause is wrong.

Comment: run "SELECT * FROM Client WHERE Name = @name" and verify that you get a result there

Comment: What is the value of `person` when you debug it?

Comment: Can you run the query outside of the application to determine if this is a valid update?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I edited my question to show the value of person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the reason the value is `System.Data.DataRowView` is because you bound your list to a `DataView`. And that's cool. But we need to take that into consideration:

```
string person = ((DataRowView)listBox2.SelectedItem)["Name"] as string;
```

Where `Name` is the name of the field that contains the person's name. I'm making an assumption that the field is named `Name`. This will fix your query.

Comment: @JAck28, fantastic. I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 4):

Did you make sure that in `person` an actual name is given, not something like a class name? If `SelectedItem` is a class, `ToString` will return the class name (*EDIT or whatever the developer returns in his own override of `ToString`*).

Set a breakpoint to the `string memberStatus = "platinum"` line and check the value for `person`.

---

Well, your `ListBox` seems to have a data binding. In that case, the actual item is a `DataRowView` and the `DisplayMember` of the `ListBox` decides what's shown in the list.

To get the person's name, you need to get the value for the "Column" from the `DataRowView`. The following line does that, assuming that the `DisplayMember` property is set to `"Name"` (substitute `"Name"` with the actual value of your `DisplayMember` property):

```
string person = ((DataRowView)listBox2.SelectedItem)["Name"] as string;
```

Comment: When I debug and hover over person, it says "System.Data.DataRowView" Why is that? How can i fix it?